# Cannot compile Qt 5.5.1 mysql plugin

Tags: kubuntu, mysql, qt5

I have system with `Kubntu 15.10` and yesterday I've ugpraded Qt version to `Qt 5.5.1 Opensource` via its `MaintenanceTool`. Today I've installed mysql development package via `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`. Now, from the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql), I've tried to compile `mysql` plugin with:
`cd /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql`
then running `qmake` with
`/opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/bin/qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/local/lib -lmysqlclient_r" mysql.pro && make all && make install`.
The compile process ends with following error:

```
g++ -c -pipe -I/usr/include/mysql -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++0x -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_MTDEV -DQT_NO_LIBUDEV -DQT_NO_TSLIB -DQT_NO_LIBINPUT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.5.0 -I/opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.5.0/QtCore -I/opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/Src/qtbase/include/QtSql/5.5.0 -I/opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/Src/qtbase/include/QtSql/5.5.0/QtSql -I../../../../include -I../../../../include/QtSql -I../../../../include/QtCore -I.moc -I../../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o .obj/qsql_mysql.o ../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.cpp
../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.cpp:36:40: fatal error: QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h: No such file or directory
 #include <QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h>
                                        ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:2003: recipe for target '.obj/qsql_mysql.o' failed
make: *** [.obj/qsql_mysql.o] Error 1
```

Now, the package `libmysqlclient-dev` info using command `dpkg -L libmysqlclient-dev|grep qsqldriver_p.h` returns no hits, that means the problematic file is not installed at all. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find it in the source directory (something like `qtbase/src/sql/kernel`) and copy it to the include directory `/opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtSql/5.5/QtSql/private`.

Answer (score 4):

The missing file `QtSql/private/qsqldriver_p.h` is in the package `qtbase5-private-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-private-dev
```